# Why it did convert to numpy.ndarray automatically?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science

I was doing the division in my database between predictors and class, so I realized I had to do LabelEncoder transformations and then OneHotEncoder, in the first database I did it like this:

```py
label_encoder_workclass = LabelEncoder()
label_encoder_education = LabelEncoder()
label_encoder_marital = LabelEncoder()
label_encoder_occupation = LabelEncoder()
label_encoder_relationship = LabelEncoder()
label_encoder_race = LabelEncoder()
label_encoder_sex = LabelEncoder()
label_encoder_country = LabelEncoder()

X_census[:,1] = label_encoder_workclass.fit_transform(X_census[:,1])
X_census[:,3] = label_encoder_education.fit_transform(X_census[:,3])
X_census[:,5] = label_encoder_marital.fit_transform(X_census[:,5])
X_census[:,6] = label_encoder_occupation.fit_transform(X_census[:,6])
X_census[:,7] = label_encoder_relationship.fit_transform(X_census[:,7])
X_census[:,8] = label_encoder_race.fit_transform(X_census[:,8])
X_census[:,9] = label_encoder_sex.fit_transform(X_census[:,9])
X_census[:,13] = label_encoder_country.fit_transform(X_census[:, 13])

onehotenconder_census = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('OneHot', OneHotEncoder(), [1,3,5,6,7,8,9,13])], remainder='passthrough')

X_census = onehotenconder_census.fit_transform(X_census).toarray()
```

And in the second database like this:

```py
label_encoder_personHomeOwnership = LabelEncoder()
label_encoder_loanIntent = LabelEncoder()
label_encoder_loanGrade = LabelEncoder()
label_encoder_cbPersonDefaultOnFile = LabelEncoder()

X_credit[:,2] = label_encoder_personHomeOwnership.fit_transform(X_credit[:,2])
X_credit[:,4] = label_encoder_loanIntent.fit_transform(X_credit[:,4])
X_credit[:,5] = label_encoder_loanGrade.fit_transform(X_credit[:,5])
X_credit[:,9] = label_encoder_personHomeOwnership.fit_transform(X_credit[:,9])

oneHotEncoder_credit = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('OneHot', OneHotEncoder(), [2,4,5,9])], remainder='passthrough')

X_credit = oneHotEncoder_credit.fit_transform(X_credit)
```

What intrigued me was why in the first one I had to use the `toarray()` method to convert it to an object of type numpy.ndarray and in the second one I didn't, it converted automatically.

Please someone take this question from me. Did I do something wrong?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [help page of ColumnTransformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html) :

> sparse_thresholdfloat, default=0.3
>
> If the output of the different transformers contains sparse matrices,
> these will be stacked as a sparse matrix if the overall density is
> lower than this value. Use sparse_threshold=0 to always return dense.
> When the transformed output consists of all dense data, the stacked
> result will be dense, and this keyword will be ignored.

In your case, the first example has more sparse entries than the second, hence it was converted to a sparse matrix. The `.toarray()` method converts it from sparse to dense.

If memory is not an issue, setting it to `sparse_threshold=0` will ensure you get a dense matrix every time.

For example if we have columns with a lot of categories:

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(111)

X = np.random.randint(0,10,(100,10))
ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('OneHot', OneHotEncoder(),
np.arange(10))], remainder='passthrough')

type(ct.fit_transform(X))
scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix

ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('OneHot', OneHotEncoder(),
np.arange(10))], remainder='passthrough',sparse_threshold=0)

type(ct.fit_transform(X))
numpy.ndarray
```

As compared to columns with less categories:

```
X = np.random.randint(0,2,(100,10))
ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('OneHot', OneHotEncoder(),
np.arange(10))], remainder='passthrough')

type(ct.fit_transform(X))
numpy.ndarray
```

Comment: Thanks man, that helps me, but i have one question, should i allways use sparse_threshold=0?

Comment: Yes you can do that but bear in mind sparse memory is there to limit memory use, especially when you have a large training set. So check how big is your final output matrix.